# How to write a DNS record for subdomain?

Tags: dns

There is a domain: `example.gov.en` 
And its subdomain: `subdomain.example.gov.en`

When I send mail to `user1@example.gov.en` - it is ok, works. But when I send mail to `user2@subdomain.example.gov.en` - it gives error:

```
error while sending email: The following addresses had permanent fatal errors, reason: 550 user2@subdomain.example.gov.en recipient unknown
```

IP address of mail server is same for domain and subdomain.

How could I write dns record for its subdomain?

My current records for this domain are these:

```
example.gov.en.     IN     A        192.168.1.1
example.gov.en.     IN     MX  10   example.gov.en.
```

Comment: I wonder if this would be more appropriate over on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), since there's no UNIX components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an MX (Mail eXchanger) record for the subdomain, so that other systems know how to deliver email to it:

```
example.gov.en.               IN     A        192.168.1.1
example.gov.en.               IN     MX  10   example.gov.en.
subdomain.example.gov.en.     IN     MX  10   example.gov.en.
```

Once you've got this working you should look at DMARC and SPF entries too, so as to minimise fraudulent emails claiming to come *from* your domains. You'll need records for these against all domains and subdomains from which you might send email.

Comment: Note to the OP: The new "subdomain" also does not start working automagically after setting up DNS. The MTA/mailboxes, depending on setup, need also to be told about it. I would advise thinking a little more and not doing things at random.